# Некорректное отображение блоков с библиотекой AOS

Tags: вёрстка, gulp, плагин, блок, библиотека

Очень странное поведение плагина AOS - когда обновляешь страницу, блоки с data-aos не отображаются. Но как только в браузере нажимаешь ctrl - или ctrl +(масштаб страницы), анимация начинает нормально проигрываться, и так до первого обновления страницы.

В чем причина может быть?

AOS через gulp подключен: js:

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
return gulp.src([
        'node_modules/aos/dist/aos.js',
        'node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.js',
        'node_modules/magnific-popup/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.js'
    ])
    .pipe(concat('libs.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/js'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true }))
});
```

css через @import (Scss потом конвертируется в один style.min.css)

```
@import "../../node_modules/aos/dist/aos";
```

Ну и AOS.init(); тоже подключен в html.

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаток этой библиотеки, но в [исходниках](https://github.com/michalsnik/aos/blob/next/src/js/aos.js) все четко написано.
Есть несколько ключевых событий, на которые реагирует либа:

- `DOMContentLoaded` или `load` - инициализирует либу - вешают `handleScroll` на событие `window.onscroll`, делает первый прогон `handleScroll` (во время которого блоки должны появится/исчезнуть в зависимости от позиции скролла на текущий момент).
- `resize` и `orientationchange` - для рефреша инициализации.

Масштабирование через `ctrl+`/`ctrl-` триггерит `resize` событик и ваша либа запускается.

Вероятно, вам надо обратить внимание на свойство `offset`, которое при инициализации определяет триггер-значение отступа сверху, после которого запустить скрипт.

Answer (score 0):

Причина в slick-carousel была. 
Yugofx, спасибо за ответ, покопался в исходниках, усвоил пару полезных плюшек. 
Сам в верстке пару недель.

Вот как решилась проблема со слайдером:

```
$('.slick-div').on('init', function(event, slick){
        AOS.init();
});
```

AOS только после инициализации самого слайдера грузится теперь и все ок.